# Скрыть содержимое блока при клике на jquery

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```
    <div class="list">
        <p class="list-date">04.02.2019</p>
        <div class="list-block">
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 1</p>
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 2</p>
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
        <p class="list-date">04.02.2019</p>
        <div class="list-block">
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 1</p>
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 2</p>
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Вот у меня есть два блока list, и мне нужно чтобы при клике на list-date пряталось содержимое блока list-block именно в том блоке list, где было кликнуто по list-date.

Вот сам код jQUery:

```
$('body').on('click', '.list-date', function(){
    $('.list-block').toggleClass('hide');
});
```

CSS:

```
.hide{
    max-height: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Покажите ваш код, что сделали (или попытались) ? Для выполнения работы "мне нужно сделать, я сам не пытался" есть биржи фриланса

Comment: $('body').on('click', '.list-date', function(){
 $('.list-block').toggleClass('hide');
});

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$('body').on('click', '.list-date', function(){
    $(this).closest('.list').find('.list-block').toggle();
});
```

Comment: Спасибо, работает)

Comment: @YavDen Пожалуйста. Успехов! Знак "галочка" - слева от ответа.

Answer (score 2):

если нужно что бы пряталось и обратно появлялось то  поменять hide -> toogle

```js
$('.list-date').on('click',(event)=>{
  $(event.target).next().hide()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="list">
        <p class="list-date">04.02.2019</p>
        <div class="list-block">
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 1</p>
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 2</p>
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="list">
        <p class="list-date">04.02.2019</p>
        <div class="list-block">
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 1</p>
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 2</p>
            <p class="list-elem">Элемент 3</p>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Мне нужно было добавить класс hide для этого блока, но идею понял, спасибо

Comment: Это конечно работает, но реализация крайне ужасная!
1. Обработчик подвешивается на сам блок.
2. Используется `e.target` и метод `next()`, т.е. если банально обернуть содержимое блока `<p class="list-date">04.02.2019</p>` в `span`, ваш код перестанет работать.
3. Использование стрелочных функций при подвешивании событий вообще недопустимо, т.к. сохраняется контекст `window`

Comment: мне кажется что тут был все было важно показать подход а не то как там через next или нет.   если контекст не используется - то его можно и не хранить. сам себе придумываешь ограничения

Comment: @СергейПетрашко Если вы хотели показать подход, то выбрали самый неудачный, а ограничения не я придумываю, а вы создаете их своим кодом))
Зачем здесь вообще `e.target` если можно было написать просто `$(this)`. Давайте не будем разводить споры в комментариях, любой понимающий человек скажет, что это ужасно и рекомендовать такое новичку тем более не стоит.